# arabic alphabet with diffrence color

Tags: android

> **hi 
>   i would like a arabic textview in android with String
>   and i would like red color for  ُ ِ َ و...**
>   i try this method but dont work**

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
String mainText = "صَدَقَ الله";
      String fatha = "َ";   
      String htmlText = mainText.replaceAll(fatha,<fontcolor='#c5c5c5'>\u064F</font>");
     txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
```

> plese help me

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder under res, call it values-ar and create strings.xml inside it.

Add any word you want something like;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="tt">صَدَقَ الله</string>
</resources>
```

then, add this code before setContentview()

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

call that string by name now.
Hope this helps

Comment: it does, I tried it before posting it .. show me how you did it !